# Mule Embedded: how to run application

Tags: mule

I have a simple Mule application that runs on a standalone Mule server.
Is it possible to create a jar file for that application that would be possible to run without necessity of installing a standalone Mule server i.e. just on JRE?
Is it called mule "embedded"?
How to do it if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to embed mule into java application and a web application. Check here for more details - https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/embedding-mule-in-a-java-application-or-webapp

**Update:
How to get jar for embedding?**

1. You can checkout the Mule Community code and build the jar - https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.7.3/distributions
2. Download embedded jar from https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime.

You can then add this jar to classpath of your application jar.

Remember from document -

> Before running Mule in embedded mode in either a Java application or a Web app, be sure to manually update all the required dependencies for your application. The Mule ESB Embedded   Single .jar contains all Mule classes, but you need to include the dependencies manually.

So you might have to play around dependencies (I didnt get chance to try it out myself).

Once you have jar on class then you can follow instruction on https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/embedding-mule-in-a-java-application-or-webapp for how to start/stop/use flows.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the link already. It doesn't quite answering my question however. So, I have the app. What exactly needs to be done to make an embedded jar that would run it?

Comment: I edited my answer to add some more information. I didnt get chance to try this out but I think it might help you.

Comment: Yeah, the tricky thing is getting the dependencies. I've failed to do this manually. I hope there is way to do this using Maven with a help of mule plugin.

Comment: Try with maven pom of mule 3.7.0 at http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mule%7Cmule%7C3.7.0%7Cpom. It has dependencies there. If it works, dont forget to update back here :)